# Regex to match uri pattern in Richtext

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a richtext input having inline image url. This input is at times escaped. I want to find all url which have path like **abc/ab?** .
link for my test https://regex101.com/r/sY4eX8/3

```
regex : /src\s*=\s*\\?['"](https?)?.+?abc\/sd.+?\\?['"]/
Text : Hello check image1 src="https://abdcom/abc/sdp?a=a&ad=d" \n <br> image 2 src=\'/abc/sd\' image3 src='http:ab/abc/sdp' \n image 4 src='http://ab/abc/sdp?bc=a' image 5 src ='http//ab.com/abc/sdp' image 6src=\"./abc/sd\" and image 7 src=\"../abc/sd\"
```

The problem is inside the regex101.com it shows all 7 match but when i try to run in java/javascript it shows only 5 without proper url match, what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var re = /src\s*=\s*\\?(['"])(?:https?:\/\/)?(.*?abc\/sd.*?)\\?\1/gi; 
var str = 'kkkkkkkkk src="https://abdcom/abc/sdp?a=a&ad=d\" \n <br> src=\"/abc/sd\"  src=\'http://ab/abc/sdp\' \n ds src=\'http://ab/abc/sdp?bc=a\'fdsfsds \nsrc =\'http://ab.com/abc/sdp\' src=\"./abc/sd\" src=\"../abc/sd\"';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    console.log(m[2]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
abdcom/abc/sdp?a=a&ad=d
/abc/sd
ab/abc/sdp
ab/abc/sdp?bc=a
ab.com/abc/sdp
./abc/sd
../abc/sd
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY4eX8/6)

Comment: Thanks can you please explain what was wrong in my pattern that JS code was not working but the regex101 was.

Comment: I haven't seen your code to can't comment on that. I just tweaked your regex a bit to make it little more accurate and generated most of the code on regex101 and ran it in my browser.